# Passing variables into a function in Lua

Tags: function, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Lua, so (naturally) I got stuck at the first thing I tried to program. I'm working with an example script provided with the Corona Developer package. Here's a simplified version of the function (irrelevant material removed) I'm trying to call:

```
function new( imageSet, slideBackground, top, bottom )

    function g:jumpToImage(num)

            print(num)
            local i = 0
            print("jumpToImage")
            print("#images", #images)
            for i = 1, #images do
                if i < num then
                    images[i].x = -screenW*.5;
                elseif i > num then
                    images[i].x = screenW*1.5 + pad
                else
                    images[i].x = screenW*.5 - pad
                end
            end
            imgNum = num
            initImage(imgNum)
        end

end
```

If I try to call that function like this:

```
local test = slideView.new( myImages )
test.jumpToImage(2)
```

I get this error:

> attempt to compare number with nil

at line 225. It would seem that "num" is not getting passed into the function. Why is this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Where are you declaring `g`? You're adding a method to `g`, which doesn't exist (as a local). Then you're never returning g either. But most likely those were just copying errors or something. The real error is probably the notation that you're using to call test:jumpToImage.

You declare `g:jumpToImage(num)`. That colon there means that the first argument should be treated as `self`. So really, your function is `g.jumpToImage(self, num)`

Later, you call it as `test.jumpToImage(2)`. That makes the actual arguments of `self` be 2 and `num` be nil. What you want to do is `test:jumpToImage(2)`. The colon there makes the expression expand to `test.jumpToImage(test, 2)`

Take a look at [this](http://www.lua.org/pil/16.html) page for an explanation of Lua's `:` syntax.